# GetStream add activity fails due 403

Tags: swift, getstream-io

Trying out GetStream for Swift, I am not able to add an activity.

```
class MyActivity : Activity {}

...

let client = Client(apiKey: <MyApiKey>, appId: <MyApiKey>, token: <Token>)
let ericFeed = client.flatFeed(feedSlug: "user", userId: "eric")
let activity = MyActivity(actor: "eric", verb: "waves", object: "picture:10", foreignId: "picture:10")
ericFeed.add(activity) { result in
        print("!result!")
        print(result)
    }
```

The `token` is generated server-side, is in form `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiZXJpYyJ9.AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAA` and:

1. `client.currentUserId` returns `eric` (So, the token is correct?)
2. The Callback of `ericFeed.add(activity)` is not called
3. On my app's dashboard log, I see the attempt of adding the activity as failed, with error 403

I tried different ids (with different tokens), both `actor: "eric"` and `actor: "user:eric"`. What could have gone wrong?

The code to generate the token (php server) is:

```
$userId = "eric";
$client = new GetStream\Stream\Client(<MyApiKey>, <MyAppSecret>);
$userToken = $client->createUserSessionToken($userId);
```

And I receive to logs on my dashboard:

[image: log1]

---

[image: log2]

Comment: can you share the code used to generate the token?

Comment: FTR the token is made of three sections separated by a dot (a.b.c). It is safe to share the actual token if you redact the last section (eg. a.b.[redacted]). Can you do that?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli sure, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple things that needs to keep in mind.
First of all, probably your client was deallocated when the request was ended and that's why the callback wasn't called, but logs could show you that the request was done. I suggest you to use a shared Client instance and it would be easy to use. To setup a shared Client you need to write this:

```
Client.config = .init(apiKey: "<MyApiKey>", appId: "<MyApiKey>", token: "<Token>")
```

More about the Client setup in [wiki page](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-swift/wiki/Setup-Client).

The second important thing, that you have to create/update your Stream user. From the server side you are getting your Token with the Stream `userId` and can request the Stream user. The easiest way is to call `Client.shared.create(user:)` where user would be created/updated. So, it's still a part of the Stream Client setup:

```
Client.shared.create(user: GetStream.User(id: Client.shared.currentUserId!)) { result in
    // Update the client with the current user.
    Client.shared.currentUser = try? result.get()
    // Do all your requests from here. Reload feeds and etc.
}
```

More info in [docs](https://getstream.github.io/stream-swift/Classes/Client.html#/s:9GetStream6ClientC6create4user11getOrCreate10completion4Moya11Cancellable_px_Sby6ResultAJOyxAA0C5ErrorOGctAA12UserProtocolRzlF).

I suggest you to create feeds with only `feedSlug` parameter and the Stream `userId` would be taken from the Token. But it would be Optional, because the `currentUserId` is optional. For example:

```
let ericFeed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "user")
ericFeed?.add(activity)
```

And for your activities, Stream clients should always use the current Stream user as an actor. So, we need to update the definition of your `MyActivity`.

Finally, here is your code that should works:

```
// Define your activity.
class MyActivity: EnrichedActivity<GetStream.User, String, DefaultReaction> {
// ...
}

// Setup Stream Client.
Client.config = .init(apiKey: <MyApiKey>, appId: <MyApiKey>, token: <Token>)

// Setup the current user.
Client.shared.getCurrentUser {
    let ericFeed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "user")
    let activity = MyActivity(actor: Client.shared.currentUser!, verb: "waves", object: "picture:10", foreignId: "picture:10")
    ericFeed?.add(activity) { result in
        print("!result!")
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Client.shared.getCurrentUser`'s callback returns now "failure: User not found". The variable ericFeed is not-nil, and addActivity's callback is still not called.

Isn't `getCurrentUser` supposed to create the user if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, `getCurrentUser` should create or update (if it exists) the user for you.
Did you try to use shared Client?

Comment: Yes, I use now `Client.config = .init(apiKey: "<MyApiKey>", appId: "<MyApiKey>", token: "<Token>")`

Comment: Can you enable client logs and print them here with the error message?

`Client.config = .init(apiKey: "<MyApiKey>", appId: "<MyApiKey>", token: "<Token>", logsEnabled: true)`

Comment: Yes, I have added them on the question

Comment: @SimoneChelo did you update your code to use "actor: Client.shared.currentUser!"?

Comment: Thanks! Could you additionally print the logs from the client in Xcode, with `logsEnabled: true`.

Comment: @SimoneChelo Please check my answer updates. You need to fix the definition of your `MyActivity`.
We'll update our docs.

Comment: The problem is that `Client.shared.getCurrentUser` still returns nil, and `Client.shared.currentUser!` will be nil (so, I cannot instantiate the activity object)

Comment: In particular, `Client.shared.getCurrentUser` returns `{"detail":"User does not exist","status_code":404,"code":16,"exception":"DoesNotExistException","duration":"2.29ms"}`

Comment: @SimoneChelo My bad. Please check my updates in the answer how to create the current user. If you will use your own User type, so, it would be needed to change `GetStream.User` to your type.

Comment: At last, an "Add Activity" call went through, thanks! Still, the feed's callback is not getting called :(